# orderBy Dataframe on two or three columns based on a condition spark scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dynamic

I am struggling with this problem using Spark Scala:

I have an inmutable value 'iter' which can be initialised to 1 or 2.

Depending on the value of 'iter', if it is 1 I need to create a new Dataframe which is the previous one sorted by two columns, otherwise I need to create a new Dataframe which is the previous one sorted by three columns.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
val df32 = Seq((1,"VZ",30,"IL"),(2, "AK", 31,"CA"),(3,"BK", 15,"KT"),(4,"CK",10,"NY"),(4,"CK",25,"YNZ"),(1,"VK",30,"IL"),(1,"VK",32,"LI")).toDF("policyId", "name", "premium", "state")

val iter = 1

if (iter == 1){
  val df_2 = df32.orderBy(asc("policyId"),asc("premium"))
}
else{
  val df_2 = df32.orderBy(asc("name"),asc("policyId"),asc("premium"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df_2` needs to be the return value of the `if-else`-block:

```
val df_2 = if (iter == 1){
  df32.orderBy(asc("policyId"),asc("premium"))
}
else{
  df32.orderBy(asc("name"),asc("policyId"),asc("premium"))
}
```